# A confusion about closed and bounded set is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Consider the discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$. That is $$\begin{align*}
d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 1 & x \neq y \\ \\ 0  & x=y
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$ Then consider the closed ball $$\begin{align*}
\overline{B}(0,1) =\left\{  x \in   \mathbb{R}: d(0,x) \leq 1 \right\}
\end{align*}$$ I think this closed ball is just entire space $\mathbb{R}$ . Under this metric, it is closed and bounded.

Consider a open cover for $\mathbb{R}$  ($\overline{B}(0,1)$ ) $$\begin{align*}
\bigcup\limits_{x \in   \mathbb{R}} B\left( x , \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{align*}$$By the metric, we know that $B\left( x, \frac{1}{2} \right) = \left\{ x \right\}$ . This is a open cover for $\mathbb{R}$ ($\overline{B}(0,1)$ ).  Also, I think this open cover can not be reduced into a finite open cover.
However, in $\mathbb{R}$ isn't every closed and bounded set compact? That is, since $\overline{B}(0,1)$ is closed and bounded, shouldn't every open cover for $\overline{B}(0,1)$ can be reduced into a finite open subcover?

I'm confused here. Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: "Closed and bounded" isn't the same thing as "compact."  It's only the case in certain topologies, so using $\mathbb{R}$ to represent two different topological spaces is equivocating.  You have used $\bar{B}(0,1)$ to equivocate in the same manner, because $\overline{B(0,1)} = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Heine-Borel theorem states that in $\mathbb R^n$ with its usual topology (by which we mean the topology generated by the usual Euclidean norm), a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded with *respect to the standard Euclidean metric* (which is of course equivalent to it being bounded with respect to any metric strongly equivalent to the Euclidean metric). What is important here is that the discrete metric does *not* generate the usual topology on $\mathbb R^n$, and so the Heine-Borel theorem does not apply.

What you have done here is create an entirely different topological space out of the *set* $\mathbb R^n$ with the discrete metric, so the sets that are compact (or open or closed) are going to be different. In fact, by equipping the set $\mathbb R^n$ with the discrete metric and taking the generated topology on it, you have ended up giving $\mathbb R^n$ the discrete topology, so every set is open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the theorem you're thinking of (i.e., the Heine-Borel theorem) states that with regard to the standard metric/distance on R^n, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  If you change the metric, as you have above, the theorem no longer applies.  This is what you're encountering in your example above.

In any Hausdorff space with a topology coming from a metric, compact sets are closed and bounded.  The Heine-Borel theorem states that in R^n (and also C^n) with the usual metric, the converse holds: sets in R^n (or C^n) that are closed and bounded (with respect to the usual metric) are compact.

More generally, in a metric space (i.e., a space with a notion of distance using the open sets coming from the metric) a set is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.  (You can find definitions of these terms on Wikipedia.)  "Complete" generalizes "closed" and "totally bounded" generalizes "bounded" in the appropriate ways for more general metric spaces.

Finally, notice that compactness is a topological property (i.e., it depends only on the open sets).  Boundedness, on the other hand, is a metric property (i.e., it depends on the distance).  One can change the metric on R^n in a way that alters what sets are bounded but does not change the open sets.  This change would alter what sets are bounded without  changing what sets are compact.  So one would only expect boundedness to coincide with compactness under certain special hypotheses for particular metrics.  The notion of "totally bounded", on the other hand, is a topological notion, which was developed, in part, to capture the topological nature of compact sets.

Comment: "a set is compact if and only if it is compact."  You had a bad typo there.

Comment: I fixed the typo.